# Getting Leksah working on Mac OS X 10.5.8

Tags: macos, haskell, ghc, leksah

I'm using Mac OS X 10.5.8.  [Another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68504/what-are-my-ide-editor-choices-for-haskell) indicated that Leksah is the IDE of choice for Haskell development.

However, Leksah (version 0.10.0.4) requires GHC 7.0.3 ([problems with 6.12.2](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/4038), [problems with 6.12.3](http://code.google.com/p/leksah/issues/detail?id=164)).  Unfortunately, the newest Haskell platform available for OS X 10.5.8 is 6.12.3.

How do I get Leksah working on my Mac?  An OS upgrade is not possible.  Should I just use a different IDE/text editor?

Comment: If you can try to avoid the platform and just get the versions of the packages that you want

Comment: Also, now vim and leksah are tied for Haskell IDE Editor of Choice by my downvote ;)

Answer (score 3):

According to the latest [State of Haskell](http://blog.johantibell.com/2011/08/results-from-state-of-haskell-2011.html) survey, the most popular IDE's are vi and Emacs, both of which have Haskell-mode features and are quite usable on OS X.

That said, it's probably worthwhile to get ghc-7 anyway.  Is self-compiling an option?  You can install a [ghc-6.12 binary](http://haskell.org/ghc/download_ghc_6_12_3#macosxintel), then use that to bootstrap compiling ghc-7.0.3.  Once you have a working ghc-7, download the [Haskell Platform Source](http://lambda.galois.com/hp-tmp/2011.2.0.1/haskell-platform-2011.2.0.1.tar.gz) and build that.  Compiling both ghc and the full platform will take a while, but I'd expect it all should work.

Answer (score 0):

This is ghc 7.0.4 for Leopard PPC: [https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.0.4/krabby/](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/7.0.4/krabby/)
I was also able to use it to build ghc 7.6.3.